# Python: Passing a class name as a parameter to a function?

Tags: python, function

```
class TestSpeedRetrieval(webapp.RequestHandler):
  """
  Test retrieval times of various important records in the BigTable database 
  """
  def get(self):
      commandValidated = True 
      beginTime = time()
      itemList = Subscriber.all().fetch(1000) 

      for item in itemList: 
          pass 
      endTime = time()
      self.response.out.write("<br/>Subscribers count=" + str(len(itemList)) + 
           " Duration=" + duration(beginTime,endTime))
```

How can I turn the above into a function where I pass the name of the class?
In the above example, Subscriber (in the Subscriber.all().fetch statement) is a class name, which is how you define data tables in Google BigTable with Python.

I want to do something like this:

```
       TestRetrievalOfClass(Subscriber)  
or     TestRetrievalOfClass("Subscriber")
```

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
class TestSpeedRetrieval(webapp.RequestHandler):
  """
  Test retrieval times of various important records in the BigTable database 
  """
  def __init__(self, cls):
      self.cls = cls

  def get(self):
      commandValidated = True 
      beginTime = time()
      itemList = self.cls.all().fetch(1000) 

      for item in itemList: 
          pass 
      endTime = time()
      self.response.out.write("<br/>%s count=%d Duration=%s" % (self.cls.__name__, len(itemList), duration(beginTime,endTime))

TestRetrievalOfClass(Subscriber)
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could pass a class just like any other variable.  I was missing that connection.

Comment: functions, methods, class, modules everything is a first class object in python which you can pass around

Answer (score 12):

If you pass the class object directly, as in your code between "like this" and "or",
you can get its name as the `__name__` attribute.

Starting with the name (as in your code *after* "or") makes it REALLY hard (and not unambiguous) to retrieve the class object unless you have some indication about where the class object may be contained -- so why not pass the class object instead?!

Comment: +1: Classes are first-class objects -- you can assign them to variables and parameters and everything.  This isn't C++.

Comment: OBJ = globals()[className]()  where className is the variable containing the string of the name of the class.   Got this from an old post here: http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13106

Comment: @NealWalters, that won't work if the class is defined anywhere ELSE than at top-level in the current module (in a function, in another class, in another module, and so forth), so not a good idea in general.

Comment: **@Ned Batchelder**, **@Alex Martelli**, what would be *most* appropriate [*type-annotation*](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html) (`Python 3.6+`) for a *class-name* argument? [@Mikhail Gerasimov says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34578836/3679900) I could use `Callable` but that sounds misleading

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation of Ned's code that I used.  This is a web application, 
so I start it by running the get routine via a URL: http://localhost:8080/TestSpeedRetrieval.  I didn't see the need of the **init**.

```
class TestSpeedRetrieval(webapp.RequestHandler):
  """
  Test retrieval times of various important records in the BigTable database 
  """
  def speedTestForRecordType(self, recordTypeClassname):
      beginTime = time()
      itemList = recordTypeClassname.all().fetch(1000) 
      for item in itemList: 
          pass # just because we almost always loop through the records to put them somewhere 
      endTime = time() 
      self.response.out.write("<br/>%s count=%d Duration=%s" % 
         (recordTypeClassname.__name__, len(itemList), duration(beginTime,endTime)))

  def get(self):

      self.speedTestForRecordType(Subscriber) 
      self.speedTestForRecordType(_AppEngineUtilities_SessionData) 
      self.speedTestForRecordType(CustomLog)
```

Output:

```
Subscriber count=11 Duration=0:2
_AppEngineUtilities_SessionData count=14 Duration=0:1  
CustomLog count=5 Duration=0:2
```