# PEP0484 Type Hinting: Annotating argument of given class, not instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

Let me explain with some sample, first.
Suppose there is a web API client module (MyAPIClient), a mapper class that converts arbitrary response into Python object (ObjectMapper), and a class that represents response object (User and Message).

```
class User(MyResponse):
    def __init__(self, status: int, id: int, name: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(status)
        self.id = int
        self.name = name

class Message(MyResponse):
    def __init__(self, status: int, id: int, text: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(status)
        self.id = int
        self.text = name

class ObjectMapper(object):
    def __init__(self, mapping_class: ???) -> None:
        self.mapping_class = mapping_class

    def map(self, obj) -> MyResponse:
        return self.mapping_class(**kwargs)

class MyAPIClient(object):
    def __init__(self, ...) -> None:
        pass

    def get_current_user(...) -> User:
        self.request("GET", "/current_user", ObjectMapper(User))

    def get_message(...) -> Message:
        self.request("GET", "/message", ObjectMapper(Message))

    def request(method: str, endpoint: str, mapper: ObjectMapper):
        res = requests.request(...)
        return json.loads(response.content.decode(), object_hook=mapper.map)
```

As shown in the sample above, ObjectMapper receives an argument named "mapping_class." This is **NOT** an instance of the class, but a class itself as shown in *MyAPIClient#get_current_user* and *MyAPIClient#get_message*. My question is how I should annotate this mapping_class in the **ObjectMapper#__init__** which is currently marked as "???" in the sample above.

Comment: I am not familiar with PEP 484, but all classes are instances of ``type``. If this helps you, feel free to post it as an answer yourself, because I cannot judge the applicability with respect to PEP 484.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that up, @JonasWielicki.
I actually tried going with "type," but kind of gaveup because... 1)  mypy complains "error: 'type' not callable," and 2) assigning "type" seems too broad, so I'd like to narrow it down to something related to "MyResponse" class in the sample above because it's the base class of "User" and "Message".

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. However mypy and PyCharm complain "not callable" error. Since the code is expecting to receive the instance of MyResponse or its subclasses instance, it's natural that it complains "not callable" because any of them has __call__ implemented and I'm not going to. So here comes the initial question, how to let them know we are just passing class, not instance...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham 'mapping_class: MyResponse' - is wrong: type(MyResponse) != type(MyResponse())

Comment: Just declare with "mapping_class: type".  PyCharm won't complain about it anymore, but mypy returns "error: 'type' not callable" on the calling part; "self.mapping_class(**kwargs)".

Comment: @Oklahomer,  I don't think you are going to satisfy mypy whatever you do, using Callable as suggested will give you a parse error and every other combination of what has been  suggested will give at least one warning

Comment: Now I'm feeling that there is no single correct solution that satisfy all...

Comment: The only thing that would definitely mean to errors would be `mapping_class: Any`

Answer (score 28):

Use [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) to refer to classes themselves:

```
class ObjectMapper(object):
    def __init__(self, mapping_class: Type[MyResponse]) -> None:
        self.mapping_class = mapping_class

    def map(self, obj) -> MyResponse:
         return self.mapping_class(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Class itself is [callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable), that returns instance of that class. Solution can be:

```
mapping_class: Callable[..., MyResponse]
```

Comment: Pycharm etc.. would still complain, object is not callable

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's not about solution, but about Pycharm doesn't support "Callable" annotation yet, see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17888 You can vote for that issue :)

Comment: I could pass `ObjectMapper(Foo)` where Foo has no relation to MyResponse and it would work fine

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, why? "Callable[..., MyResponse]" says that return value should be instance of "MyResponse". Instance of "Foo" is not instance of "MyResponse".

Comment: That is my point, you can pass anything and there is no warning or error

Comment: @PadraicCunningham for now, yes. But as soon as "Callable" support would be implemented, solution should work fine. Anyway, I don't think there's any other solution, because PEP has no explicit way to annotate variable as class.

Comment: So with the suggested one the signature would be "Accepts **any** callable that returns MyResponse ( or its subclasses' ) instance." It just doesn't seem what we really want for, but yeah you said it: "PEP has no explicit way to annotate variable as class."

Comment: @Oklahomer, you're right, it's not strict solution, it would accept "any callable". But I think in most cases it's what we really need for: nothing bad with passing some factory function to mapping_class in real life. Only case when solution will fail is when we use some class-only specific attributes, but I think it's fairly rare situation. Well, if your case is second you may want to write mail to typing and mypy author http://www.mypy-lang.org/contact.html or to python bug-tracker https://bugs.python.org/