# How to pass a class as a parameter and inherit methods

Tags: python

I've already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436444/python-passing-a-class-name-as-a-parameter-to-a-function) but I would like to inherit of the methods of the class in parameter.

Example:

```
class TypeOfGame1(object):
    def get_max_players(self):
        return 2

class TypeOfGame2(object):
    def get_max_players(self):
        return 30

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, game_cls):
        self.game = game_cls()
```

Then from this code above how could I do stuff like:

```
a = Game(TypeOfGame1)
a.get_max_players()  # should return 2
a = Game(TypeOfGame2)
a.get_max_players()  # should return 30
```

Comment: I want to be as shortest and as easy to understand in the long run. `a.game.get_max_players()` is longer than `a.get_max_players()` (and I have a lot of comparisons and so on going on)

Comment: You'd have to implement `__getattr__` to look up any missing attributes on `self.game`. It all seems a bit backwards - shouldn't `TypeOfGame1` be an instance or subclass of `Game`?

Comment: Yep, maybe inherit with class `Game(TypeOfGame1, TypeOfGame2)` and then depending on the parameter of the constructor, choose which call to make? If it's possible (I guess so) I dont know how

Comment: That still seems backwards. Just do `class Game1(Game):` then set a `self.max_players` attribute in the subclass `__init__` that you use in the superclass `get_max_players` (or use a property, or just *access the attribute*). Composition seems like a weird way to approach this when each game *is a* game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly how about using `__getattr__` to proxy your class?

```
n [2]: class Game(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, game_cls):
   ...:         self.game = game_cls()
   ...:     def __getattr__(self, other):
   ...:         return getattr(self.game, other)
   ...:

In [7]: g = Game(TypeOfGame1)

In [8]: g.get_max_players()
Out[8]: 2

In [11]: g = Game(TypeOfGame2)

In [12]: g.get_max_players()
Out[12]: 30
```

Comment: Does this pass parameters as well?

Comment: it will pass all undefined methods/attributes to `__getattr__` so yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, but you can use the `game` object instead:

```
>>> a = Game(TypeOfGame1)
>>> a.game.get_max_players()
2
>>> a = Game(TypeOfGame2)
>>> a.game.get_max_players()
30
```

or implement the methods in the `game` object as proxies in your `Game` class:

```
class Game(object):
    ...
    def get_max_players(self):
        return self.game.get_max_players()
```

Comment: I want to be as shortest and as easy to understand in the long run. `a.game.get_max_players()` is longer than `a.get_max_players()` (and I have a lot of comparisons and so on going on)

Comment: Or maybe inherit with class `Game(TypeOfGame1, TypeOfGame2)` and then depending on the parameter of the constructor, choose which call to make? If it's possible (I guess so) I dont know how

Comment: @OlivierPons If you make it shorter you can implement all the methods if they are known. See my updated answer.

Comment: Proxy = nice idea!